# Gulp run task after task

Tags: css, node.js, gulp

I have a problem with running task after an other.

Task 1 : List and rewrite css files
Task 2 : Concat and prefix the new css file

When I launch the sequence task the debug() shows **gulp-debug: 0 items** when second task is launching.

But files are created after first task.

If I launch again a second time the sequence, second task see old files.

Can you help me :)

This my gulpfile :

```
    gulp.task('plugins-rename-url-css', function() {

    var sources = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test/css.json'));

    var tasks = sources.global.files.map(function(file) {

            var folder = file.substring(0,file.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

            return gulp.src('test/'+file)
                .pipe(replaceTasks({
                    patterns: [
                        {
                            match: /url\([\'\"]?(?!\/)([A-Za-z0-9-_\.\/\@]+)[\'\"]?\)/g,
                            replacement: 'url(' + folder + '$1)'
                        }
                    ]
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('test/tmp/'));

    });
    return tasks;

});


gulp.task('concat-prefix-css', function(){
    return gulp.src('test/tmp/*.css')
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(concat('_global.css'))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
            cascade: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('test/tmp2/'));
    done();
 });

gulp.task('css-tasks',['plugins-rename-url-css','concat-prefix-css']);



Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
Starting 'plugins-rename-url-css'...
Finished 'plugins-rename-url-css' after 33 ms
Starting 'concat-prefix-css'...
gulp-debug: 0 items
Finished 'concat-prefix-css' after 19 ms
Starting 'css-tasks'...
Finished 'css-tasks' after 14 μs
```

Comment: Did you tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence ?

Comment: Yes, same problem :s